# how to retrieve data from database when i click on listitem android ?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an application , i have created a listview where i can retreive data from mysql database. IT's working very good. 
But the problem is that i want to load the data of each item in another activity with details from the database .
Can anyone help me please ?? i'm really stuck , i don't how to do it.
This is my java code :

```
public class GererUtilisateur extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private ArrayList<ClassListItem> itemArrayListU;
    private MyAppAdapterU myAppAdapterU;
    private ListView listViewU;
    private boolean succes = false;

    private static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2/test3_10032018";
    private static final String USER="";
    private static final String PASS="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gerer_utilisateur);
        listViewU=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listuser);
        itemArrayListU = new ArrayList<ClassListItem>();
        SynDataU orderData = new SynDataU();
        orderData.execute();




    }
    private class SynDataU extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        String msg="";
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                if (connection == null) {
                    succes = false;
                } else {
                    String query = "SELECT id_utilisateur , nom , prenom , fonction FROM utilisateur";
                    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if (rs != null) {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            try {
                                itemArrayListU.add(new ClassListItem(rs.getInt("id_utilisateur"), rs.getString("nom"), rs.getString("prenom") , rs.getString("fonction")));
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        succes = true;
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                msg = writer.toString();
                succes = false;
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GererUtilisateur.this,"Synchronising","ListView Loading !!!",true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (succes = false){
            }else{
                try{
                    myAppAdapterU = new MyAppAdapterU(itemArrayListU,GererUtilisateur.this);
                    listViewU.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    listViewU.setAdapter(myAppAdapterU);



                }catch (Exception ex){
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyAppAdapterU extends BaseAdapter {
        public class ViewHolder{
            TextView id;
            TextView prenom;
            TextView nom;
            TextView fonction;
        }
        public List<ClassListItem> decisionList;

        public Context context;
        ArrayList<ClassListItem> arrayList;

        private MyAppAdapterU(List<ClassListItem> apps,Context context){
            this.decisionList= apps;
            this.context=context;
            arrayList= new ArrayList<ClassListItem>();
            arrayList.addAll(decisionList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return decisionList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if(rowView==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content,parent,false);
                viewHolder= new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.id=rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
                viewHolder.nom=rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nom);
                viewHolder.prenom=rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_prenom);
                viewHolder.fonction=rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_fonc);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);


            }else
            {
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }
            viewHolder.id.setText(decisionList.get(position).getId()+"");
            viewHolder.nom.setText(decisionList.get(position).getNom()+"");
            viewHolder.prenom.setText(decisionList.get(position).getPrenom()+"");
            viewHolder.fonction.setText(decisionList.get(position).getFonction()+"");

            return rowView;
        }



    }
    public void ajout(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AjouterUtil.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

And this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mootaz.mobilevoting.GererUtilisateur"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_ajout"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"


        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/BlueGrayLight"
       >





        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listuser"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_ajout"
        style="@style/RaisedButtonA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:onClick="ajout"
        android:text="Ajouter Utilisateur" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="Gerer les utilisateurs"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FirstActivity add this.

```
listViewU.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
        // retrieve from movie whatever you want
        movie.getName();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name: "+movie.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // creaet intent and add data to it.
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtra("name",movie.getName()); 
        startActivity(intent);
     }
});
```

In your second activity get data like this.

```
// get info from intent
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = bundle.getString("name");
```